# Send and receive raw 802.11 frames on Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I'm looking for a way to send and receive raw 802.11 frames using USB wireless adapters (such as the [Alfa AWUS036H](http://www.alfa.com.tw/products_show.php?pc=34&ps=92)) while they are in monitor mode. Is this possible?

There are plenty of ways to do this at the MAC layer, but I have yet to find one allowing this at the physical layer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I figured this out right after asking...

To anyone else trying to achieve this, a (somewhat) device independent library has been developed for this: [LORCON](https://code.google.com/p/lorcon/)

Comment: Just to be clear, lorcon lets you inject packets at the 802.11 MAC layer (that is, you can specify your own MAC-layer headers). I'm pretty sure it doesn't actually let you get down to the physical layer (it doesn't let you manipulate the PLCP preamble or PLCP header).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
After some more research it seems that the 802.11 MAC-layer frames might be enough for my purposes.

Comment: Can I forge IEEE 802.11 headers and exploit the hole 196 vulnerability using LORCON?

Comment: In other words can it do something that tools like nemesis cannot do?